# What are the accessibility issues with nested modal dialogs

Tags: dialog, popup, accessibility, wai-aria

I am working on a website prototype and I was reading about that we shouldn't really use nested modal dialogs. I am curious about the **accessibility** issues around this. I tried searching on https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/ but there isn't any guideline around nested dialogs. I am trying to understand why is it frowned upon.

Comment: care to add the source of the article / discussion etc. that says this as a link in the question? It depends what you mean by "nested" as to whether this is a problem or not. (i.e. do you mean having the modal dailog's HTML within another modal dialog's HTML (bad idea) or do you just mean multiple dialog's where one is activated from within another (could be fine).). **It all depends on implementation.** A code example of what you think is unacceptable would also be useful so we can explain any issues if they exist.

Answer (score 1):

There is no accessibility with nested modal dialogs per se.

The problem is more often caused by the fact that the UI frameworks, tools, etc. don't behave well when nesting modal dialogs, because they haven't necessarily been designed with that in mind.
This isn't as easy as it seems to do it well.
For example they can mix up aria-hidden, tabindex, focus wrapping, visual effects, etc. in an incorrect way, and those bugs eventually end up breaking accessibility or creating unexpected behaviors. This is a common trap.

However, you should ask yourself, in the point of view of **usability**, if nesting modals is really needed and useful.
Perhaps you can simplify your interface in order to never nest? This will be much more beneficial for everyone and you won't need to ask yourself the question if the UI toolkit you are using indeed well supports nested dialogs.